# Geocoding and Reverse in python using Geopy

Tags: python

I had done this program that takes an input from STDIN and processes it to check if it is a Latitude/longitude combo or a place's name. Then it uses geocoding and returns an address corresponding to the latitude longitude or returns a latitude and longitude if the input is an address. I am using [Nomatim](https://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.10.0/index.html?highlight=nominatim#geopy.geocoders.Nominatim), I would like to know how else can we do this?I would also like to know how I can make the code better.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import re
geolocator=Nominatim()
arg=raw_input()
pattern=re.compile(r'^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$')
if pattern.match(arg):
    loc=geolocator.reverse(arg)
    if loc is not None:
        print(loc.address)
        print(loc.latitude, loc.longitude)
    else:
        print "the location doesnt exist"
else:
    loc=geolocator.geocode(arg)
    if loc is not None:
        print(loc.address)
        print(loc.latitude, loc.longitude)
    else:
        print "This address does not exist"
```

Answer (score 4):

**Duplicated code**

You should try to follow the [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.
In your case, most of the logic is repeated in 2 branches.

You could write :

```
if pattern.match(arg):
    loc=geolocator.reverse(arg)
else:
    loc=geolocator.geocode(arg)
if loc is not None:
    print(loc.address)
    print(loc.latitude, loc.longitude)
else:
    print "the location doesnt exist"
```

Alternatively, this could be written using conditional expressions :

```
loc = geolocator.reverse(arg) if pattern.match(arg) else geolocator.geocode(arg)
```